# why React JS onDrop function not executing synchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actually, I am new to react js. I want to upload files on the server on the button click, and onDrop event I want to read files information like total files and files size.
but my this if statement
if(filesSize > 10000) {
console.log('inside if')
setFileSizeError(true)
}
not executing on the first drop
but working on the second drop, and console.log('inside on drop') executing before for loop.
where is the problem please tell me.

```
import '../../css/dragdropsection.css'
// import UserMessage from '../messages/UserMessage'


function DragDropSection() {
    let [validInput, setValidInput] = useState(undefined)
    let [files, setFiles] = useState([])
    let [filesSize, setFilesSize] = useState(0)
    let [fileSizeError, setFileSizeError] = useState(false)

    function handelDragEnter(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        setValidInput(true)
    }
    
    function handelDragLeave(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    function handelDragOver(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    async function traverseFileTree(item, path) {
        path = path || "";
        if (item.isFile) {
          // Get file
          item.file(function(file) {
            // console.log("File:", path + file.name);
            console.log(file)
            setFiles((pre) => [...pre, file])
            setFilesSize((pre) => pre + file.size)
            if(filesSize > 10) {
                console.log('inside if')
                setFileSizeError(true)
                setValidInput(false)   
            }
          })
        } else if (item.isDirectory) {
          // Get folder contents
          let dirReader = item.createReader();
          dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
            for (let i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
              traverseFileTree(entries[i], path + item.name + "/");
            }
          })
        }
    }

    function handelOnDrop(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        setFiles([])
        setFilesSize(0)
        setFileSizeError(false)
        // e.stopPropagation()

        let items = e.dataTransfer.items
        for (let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
            // webkitGetAsEntry is where the magic happens
            let item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();

            if (item) {
                traverseFileTree(item)
            }
            else{
                setFiles([])
                setFilesSize(0)
                return setValidInput(false)
            }
        }

        console.log('inside on drop after for loop')
        // setValidInput(undefined)
    }
    return (
        <div className="dragDropSection">

            <div onDragEnter={handelDragEnter} 
                onDragOver={handelDragOver}
                onDragLeave={handelDragLeave}
                onDrop={handelOnDrop}
                className={` dragZone ${validInput === true?  "dragEnterStyleOnValidInput" :validInput === false? "dragEnterStyleOnInvalidValidInput": "" }`}>

                <h1 className="uploadIcon"><i className="bi bi-cloud-upload"></i></h1>
                <h3>Drag and Drop file here.</h3>
                {fileSizeError? 'Upload Error: file Size Greater than 100 MB': '' }

            </div>

            <span id="dragSpan"> browse files. </span>

            <h6>Delete files from cloud after
                <select name="expireLinkTime" className="expireTimeSelector">
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                </select> hours
            </h6>

            {/* <div id="myProgress">
                <div id="myBar">20%</div>
            </div> */}

            <button id="uploadBtn">upload files</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DragDropSection
```

Comment: Where are you actually registering your listener? We need to see the full function in order to help you. Judging your names and what you're doing `handelOnDrop` seems more to be the `dragstart` event handler.

Comment: Now, I have updated